# How to make an iOS 8 share extension that will have default text

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

In my app there is text displayed in a label on screen.

I have a share button when pressed brings the UIActivityViewController  but when you press the share extensions ex: Twitter, you get the compose view with nothing inside of it.

I want it that it puts the text from the label on the screen into the compose view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you did this but it would work well.
suppose you put it on a action sheet :

```
let share = UIAlertAction(title: "Share my label!", style: .Default, handler: { action in
        let shareMessage = myLabel.text
        let itemsToShare = [shareMessage]

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemsToShare,
            applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
```

Comment: I asked for share extenion @SaeidBsn

Comment: You asked for a share extension but the description of what the rest of your question asked for sounds like `UIActivityViewController`. A share extension allows you to add a new item related to your app in the share menu of other apps.  Perhaps you could add some code to your question showing what you have tried.

Comment: @NikhilCKanamarla you can refer to this link for full sample
http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/